# Div Bleeding Down Beyond Set Margin In Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, scale, margin

I have set up a few divs on a 'responsive layout' page.

ISSUE:

When the page is scaled down, one of the 'child' divs ('headline') is bleeding down (4px) below it's set margin (bottom: 0;).

Here is the page code, including the CSS:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta name="" content="text/html; charset=utf-8, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />

    <title>Page Title</title>

    <style>

    body {margin: 0; }

    .fixed-ratio-resize {
        max-width: 100%; 
        height: auto; 
        width: auto\9;
    }

    .storyWrapper {
        position: relative; 
        max-width: 800px; 
        max-height: 450px;
        border:none;
    }

    .leftBtn {
        z-index: 100; 
        position: absolute; 
        width:4%; 
        min-height:30px; 
        padding-left:6px; 
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
        bottom:50%;
    }

    .leftBtn a{
        float: left; 
        font-family: Arial; 
        line-height:30px; 
        vertical-align:middle; 
        font-size:30px; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        color:white; 
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .rightBtn {
        z-index: 100; 
        position: absolute; 
        width:4%; 
        min-height: 30px; 
        padding-right: 6px; 
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
        margin-left: 95.1%; 
        bottom: 50%;
    }

    .rightBtn a{
        float: right; 
        font-family: Arial; 
        line-height: 30px; 
        vertical-align: middle; 
        font-size: 30px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        color: white; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .headline {
        position: absolute; 
        width: 98.5%; 
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); 
        padding: 0px 6px 0px 6px; 
        bottom: 0px;
     }

    .headline a{ 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
        line-height: 26px; 
        vertical-align: middle; 
        font-size: 16px; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        color: white; 
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    </style>

    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="story1" class="storyWrapper">
    <a href="#"><img class="fixed-ratio-resize" 
    src="CarouselAssets/carouselImages/green.jpg" width="800px" 
    height="450px" alt=""/></a>
    <div class="leftBtn"><a href="#">&#8249;</a></div>
    <div class="rightBtn"><a href="#">&#8250;</a></div>
    <div id="headline" class="headline"><a href="#">THIS IS A REBEL PLANET 
    NEWS HEADLINE FOR THE STORY ABOUT THE COLOR GREEN</a></div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is a link to the page containing this code:

http://www.rebelplanetnews.com/responsiveTest.html

I need to prevent the child 'headline' div from bleeding down past the parent 'storyWrapper' div when the page is shrunken.

*NOTE: The image used is simply a green jpg image (w 800 X h 450)

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `display: block` to your `a` element (parent of the `.fixed-ratio-resize` class). Since this is an `a` element, it will be `inline` display. You will have to change to a `block` element.

You can also apply `display: block` the entire class of `.fixed-ratio-resize` in order to deal with browser support and being able to click the entire image.

Comment: That did it! Thank you!